# Unable to retrieve package records when using restore

Tags: r, packrat

I am developing an R package and I am using `packrat` to manage dependencies.

After I installed `dplyr` in the project library I get the following error when I use `packrat::restore()`:

```
Errore: Unable to retrieve package records for the following packages:
- 'demandr'
```

Where `demandr` is the name of the package I am working on. Any suggestion?

Comment: Any solution for this?